# ResourceManager set wrong on save

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am having a issue where every time i change my resource files, the ResourceManager is set with a invalid path.

Example

```
namespace bundlrs_MVC6.Resources {
...    
global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.ResourceManager("bundlrs_MVC6.HomeIndexViewResources", typeof(HomeIndexViewResources).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

Should be: (Note the extra Resources)

```
namespace bundlrs_MVC6.Resources {
...  
global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("bundlrs_MVC6.Resources.HomeIndexViewResources", typeof(HomeIndexViewResources).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

Folder structure:

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2015

[image]

Should i move all resource files to: `namespace bundlrs_MVC6` instead of `namespace bundlrs_MVC6.Resources` if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed with the CoreCLR 1.0.0 RTM release